# Get the max length allowed in column, mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i need to know how to get the max size of an specific column in mysql, the table is

turno :

```
CREATE TABLE `turno` (  
`idTurno` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,  
`nombreTurno` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,  
`horaInicio` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,  
`horafin` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,  
`valorTurno` int(11) NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (`idTurno`)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci
```

the column :

```
`nombreTurno` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL
```

i should get :

```
20
```

im getting:

```
NULL
```

the query :

```
SELECT MAX( LENGTH( nombreTurno ) ) AS maxl
FROM turno
```

hope you can help me, thank you

Comment: do you haveany records on your table?

Comment: no i dont have any record, the value that i need is about the table's structure.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
select COLUMN_NAME, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH 
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = DATABASE() AND   -- name of your database
      table_name = 'turno' AND        -- name of your table
      COLUMN_NAME = 'nombreTurno'     -- name of the column
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ccbb5e/1)

Answer (score 2):

The following SQL query will give the maximum column length.

```
SELECT max(length(column)) `max_column_length` from tab;
```

Comment: This only provides the maximum length of the longest record saved, not actually the maximum length the column is set to be capable of in the table setup.