# How to get no of bytes occupied by a column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I need to know how many bytes are occupied by a column in MySQL.

Consider the following schema -

```
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| data  | longblob            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Ignore `id` field, lets talk about `data` field. Consider these tuples -

```
+-------+---------------------+
| id    | data                |
+-------+---------------------+
|   1   | {ab₹}               |
|   2   | {ab}                |
+-------+---------------------+
```

So, what I need is size in bytes not no of characters like-

```
+---------------------+
| size_in_bytes       | 
+---------------------+
|                   7 |     // {->(1), a->(1), b->(1), ₹->(3), }->(1)
|                   4 |     // {->(1), a->(1), b->(1), }->(1)
+---------------------+
```

After hours of search I found few functions which only result in no of characters.

```
select OCTET_LENGTH(data) from table_name;
+--------------------+
| OCTET_LENGTH(data) |
+--------------------+
|                  5 |
|                  4 |
+--------------------+

SELECT LENGTH(data) from table_name;
+--------------+
| LENGTH(data) |
+--------------+
|            5 |
|            4 |
+--------------+

SELECT char_length(data) from table_name;
+-------------------+
| char_length(data) |
+-------------------+
|                 5 |
|                 4 |
+-------------------+
```

Similar Question -> [How to get size of column in mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21772205/how-to-get-size-of-column-in-mysql-table) but none of the answers results in bytes.

[How to get the sizes of the tables of a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620198/how-to-get-the-sizes-of-the-tables-of-a-mysql-database) and this is for size of the table.

MySQL version -> 8.0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Count bits

```
select BIT_LENGTH (N'{ab₹}')/8;
```

returns 7.0000

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=426dab7c206629943e1e22c75bdf47b8)

Comment: I swear in mysql8 o/p for ```select BIT_LENGTH (N'{ab₹}')/8;``` is ``` 5.0000```. Just now tested.

Comment: @Sathvik, see dbfiddle.

Comment: Yes it's working in dbfiddle thanks for helping. But my terminal is resulting wrong answer any idea

Comment: Probably different collation ? `SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database`

Comment: ```| utf8mb4  | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci  |``` how to set it

Comment: Hmm, what is  `hex(N'{ab₹}')` ? is it '7B6162E282B97D' like in MySql behind the fiddle?

Comment: I got ```7B61623F7D```

Comment: Is there any way to get whole column size(bytes occupied) for BLOB field using information_schema. No need for individual row size, actually I need the whole column size(in bytes).

Comment: BLOB size is not part of a table schema. All BLOBs in  a db share the same max size determined by the type itself. Row's size is varying.

Comment: Best thing is to redesign my db. I will create an extra column for size. While sending data to db I will compute it and send it.

Comment: @Sathvik You have a character encoding issue, all your characters are encoded on a single byte. The calculation method suggested here (or just using the lenght() function) is fine, your data is not fine.

Answer (score 0):

`length()` is right，about this function instruction：
[length function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html)

> Returns the length of the string str, measured in bytes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35188300)